# How to simulate commercial Double Balanced Mixer in ADS

Tags: mixer, ads

I need to simulate [ADE-1](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=ADE-1%2B) from the Mini-circuit in ADS. I use this circuit simulation in ADS.
[image].

My RF source (P_1Tone) and Lo source, in reality, generate a 2dBm and 10dBm sinewaves. However, in simulating my mixer output I encounter the "No convergence" error. When I changed the RF/Lo sources to -2dBm and -10dBm it works but the result is not acceptable. For simplicity, I used the default harmonics tables  (dbl1.imt) from the ADS library which approximately is as same as my ADE-1 harmonics tables.
I have set ConvGain to "dbpolar(dbmtow(7),0)" or even "dbpolar(dbmtow(-7),0)" but nothing works.

I need to know how to simulate my mixer based on my real RF sources in ADS.

Comment: Why not try using it at its recommended LO power, as stated in the datasheet?.

Comment: Yes, it was one of my problems, Could you let me know how to simulate a real mixer in ADS (Double balanced mixer) with harmonics table/conversion loss and LO level?